# Stripe js: uncompleted payment, payment is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

So I am working on payment processing with stripe. When I go to the payments on stripe it says they are uncompleted, the customer did not define the payment method...
React component

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getClientSecret = async () => {
      const responce = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`,
      });
      setClientSecret(responce.data.clientSecret);
    };
    getClientSecret();
  }, [basket]);

  console.log("THE SECRET IS >>> ", clientSecret);

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    //stripe magic
    e.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe
      .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements?.getElement(CardElement),
        },
      })
      .then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
        //paymentIntent = payment confirmation
        console.log(paymentIntent);
        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null);
        setProcessing(false);

        dispatch({
          type: "EMPTY_BASKET",
        });

        history.replace("/orders");
      });
  };

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    //stripe magic
    setDisabled(e.empty);
    setError(e.error ? e.error.message : "");
  };

  return (
    <div className="payment">
      <div className="payment__container">
        <h1>
          Checkout(<Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items</Link>)
        </h1>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__address">
            <p>{user?.email}</p>
            <p>123 React Lane</p>
            <p>Los Angeles, CA</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Review items and delivery</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__items">
            <FlipMove>
              {basket.map((item) => (
                <div>
                  <CheckoutProduct
                    id={item.id}
                    title={item.title}
                    image={item.image}
                    price={item.price}
                    rating={item.rating}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
            </FlipMove>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Payment Method</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__details">
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
              <CardElement onChange={changeHandler} />

              <div className="payment__priceContainer">
                <CurrencyFormat
                  renderText={(value) => (
                    <>
                      <h3>Order Total: {value}</h3>
                    </>
                  )}
                  decimalScale={2}
                  value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                  displayType={"text"}
                  thousandSeperator={true}
                  prefix={"$"}
                />
                <button
                  disabled={
                    processing || disabled || succeeded || clientSecret === null
                  }
                >
                  <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> : "Buy Now"}</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Payment;
```

Node JS

```
const app = express();

// - Middlewares
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// - API routes
app.get("/", (request, responce) => responce.status(200).send("hello world"));

app.post("/payments/create", async (request, responce) => {
  const total = request.query.total;

  console.log("Payment Request Received >>> ", total);

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: total,
    currency: "usd",
  });
  // OK - Created
  responce.status(201).send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});

// - Listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I have two questions: 1st, is this going to b a problem when working on order history? an 2nd, how do I fix this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: A payment intent will show as 'incomplete' in the dashboard if it has a `requires_confirmation`, `requires_action`, or a `requires_payment_method` status. Most of the time, what this means is that `confirmCardPayment` hasn't been called on the PaymentIntent. So to debug this you would need to check your Stripe logs in the dashboard `Developers > Logs` to see the latest requests that were made for each of those payment intents. From there you should be able to hone in on the exact problem.

Comment: So I have looked at the logs and I think the problem is that is says `"payment_method": null,`. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: At the time that the `submitHandler` is called, is `elements` defined? Could you log that and `elements?.getElement(CardElement)` to see what's being passed to Stripe.js at runtime?

Comment: Yes, it is defined, it gives me an array with a bunch of information

Comment: By the way, on the api log it also says function timed out. in te inspector console: `xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:5001/clone-f805e/us-central1/api/payments/create?total=0 net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: Hm, is `clientSecret` defined when calling the `submitHandler`? The network error you're getting implies that it wouldn't be - in which case there's likely an error server-side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227919/discussion-between-ttmarek-and-rexylp).